# Retrieve env variable of target node using ansible

Tags: bash, variables, ansible

I am trying to get env variale JAVA_HOME value of a target node using ansible.

```
- name: Copy JAVA_HOME location to variable
  command:  bash -c "echo $JAVA_HOME"
  sudo: yes
  register: java_loc
```

When i use, java_loc.stdout value in another task, it is showing blank value. How can i get that env variable and use it in another task?

I need to copy files to JAVA dir which is present in JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible logins via SSH using non-login shell. Probably your problem is that you defined the environment variable on $HOME/.bash_profile or some other file that requires login shell, so you need to add the "**-l**" flag to "**/bin/bash**":

```
---
- name: Copy JAVA_HOME location to variable 
  command:  /bin/bash -l -c "echo $JAVA_HOME"    
  sudo: no                                  
  register: java_loc                        

- name: show debug                          
  debug: var=java_loc
```

Please, give it a try and let me know,

Comment: Hi..Here is the output..    `"var": {
        "java_loc": {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": [
                "bash",
                "-c",
                "echo $JAVA_HOME"
            ],
            "delta": "0:00:00.003758",
            "end": "2015-09-21 16:23:30.922160",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "bash -c \"echo $JAVA_HOME\"",
                "module_name": "command"
            },
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2015-09-21 16:23:30.918402",
            "stderr": "",
            "stdout": "",
            "stdout_lines": [],`

Comment: Hi Alfredocambera  Nevermind .. it got worked now..  Thank you

Comment: Just did as u mentioned...initially i missed to add -l (login shell). It worked after adding that

Answer (score 0):

If your Java is sufficiently recent to have *jrunscript*, you can obtain the Java Path from your Java installation, avoiding any dependency on your environment. The code below does this, and doesn't fail if there's no *jrunscript*.

```
- name: Detemine Java home
command: 'jrunscript -e java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty(\"java.home\"));'
changed_when:  False
ignore_errors: True
register: locate_java_home

- name: Set a variable for Java home
set_fact:
    java_home: "{{ (locate_java_home.rc == 0) | ternary(locate_java_home.stdout, '') }}"
```

The solution is based on the proposal made [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/657468/488782).